# using last after model included doesnt work

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-3

Im stuck (still very new to Rails), and cant figure out why its not working:

I have:

```
    class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :updated_at
     has_many :categories_messages
     has_many :categories, through: :categories_messages
    end

    class CategoriesMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :category_id, :message_id
     belongs_to :category
     belongs_to :message
    end

    class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :name
     has_many :categories_messages
     has_many :message, through: :categories_messages
    end

    @messagesPer = Category.all.includes(:messages).group('categories.id').order("COUNT(messages.id) DESC")


    <% @messagesPer.each_with_index do |message,  i| %>
         <tr>
            <td><%= i+1 %></td> 
            <td><%= message.name %></td>
            <% if message.categories_messages.exists? %>
                <td><%= message.messages.last.updated_at.to_s.to_date %></td>
                <td><%= message.messages.first.updated_at.to_s.to_date %></td>
                <td><%= message.messages.count %></td>
            <% else %>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

So i want it to show :
the name of Category, date the last message was created , date first message was created, and all messages in that category.

ALl works fine, apart from the fact that it only shows the date when the first message was created, but never the last (still shows first date on the last).
What am i doing wrong?

UPDATE:

if i put

```
     @messagesPer = Category.all.includes(:messages).group('categories.id')
```

it does show the right date for last and first messages but as soon as i add order it breaks...

Answer (score 0):

I might be helpful to include the error information you get after adding an order clause to the query.

However, I can spot some odd things in the code. The `CategoriesMessage` model seems to be there simply to satisfy the condition that a category can have many messages and vice versa. You don't need a model for this many-to-many relationship though, Rails will handle this automatically for you.

Your models should be looking like this:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :updated_at
 has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name
 has_and_belongs_to_many :messages
end
```

And in your database you have these tables: `messages`, `categories,`categories_messages`, where the last one is the join table which only contains columns for a`message_id`and a`category_id`.

Then you can simply do something like this in your code:

```
category.messages.each { |message| puts message.updated_at }
```

Also see [this Ruby on Rails tutorial article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) for more information. If this doesn't work for you, please post the exact error you get.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The problem is that i dont get the error, it just shows the same date for first message and for the last message, although that is not so in the database.

Comment: a wild guess?!: could it be cause of the fact that not every category has messages and im forcing them to order by messages , so it doesnt like it?

Comment: Alternatively you could check the logs to see exactly which SQL query is being executed, that might give you more insight into the problem.